# i want to hide a save button in my master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a multiview having view1 and view2. view1 i have to save some details to my database and view2 i have a gridview. when loading view1 i want to show the save button in the masterpage.if loading view2 save button want to hide from master page

Comment: If the save button appears only in view1 then move it to view1.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the master page using [Page.Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) property. For example,

in master page code behind

```
public partial class MyMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
   public void ToggleSaveButton(bool visible)
   {
     SaveButton.Visible = visible
   }

   // other code
   ...
}
```

And in your page

```
((MyMasterPage)Master).ToggleSaveButton(true);
```

Comment: Do you need to pass in a bool to an `xToggle` function? E.g

`SaveButton.Visible = ! SaveButtonVisible;`

Comment: @5arx - point noted - perhaps, `setSaveButtonVisibility` would have been appropriate name? BTW, toggleX may have a bool - refer jquery overload `.toggle( showOrHide )`. On different note, toggle functionality would not be helpful here because it would entail tracking button state over view traversal.

Comment: @VinayC - I'm not sure what you mean re: view traversal - can you explain further please?

Comment: @5arx, OP is using multi-view where he wants to show save button for few views - so whenever view is switched, he needs to set save button visibility for current view (as opposed to toggling where when user traverse from view A to B, one needs to determine if View A & B both have same save visibility requirement - if no then toggle).

Comment: Ohh now I understand fully. Something to read about - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = Master.FindControl("your button id") as Button;
button.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it client side you can either use JQuery or Javascript because the master page control will also be rendered and hecnce you can easily find it using `JQuery : $("#ControlId").css("display","none")` , Javascript : document.getElementById(...) and set its display to none.